# Is there way to configure magento to bcc an email in every mail send out on an order?

Tags: email, email-templates

I need to send a copy of the order email to a particular email address every time an success order was placed. Is there way to configure this in magento without modifying or rewriting the sales order class ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Magento Admin Panel, go to **System** > **Configuration**  and in left tabs find **Sales**

Under sales select **'Sales Emails'** , there in every tab and for every email type: order or invoice or shipment, there is option: **Send Order Email Copy To** write your desired email address here.

Select **"Send Order Email Copy Method"** if you want to send it as **separate email** or as **BCC**.

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Do you think there is a way to configure bcc for the reset password attempts ?

Comment: @ted Probably not - for security reasons

Answer (score 4):

Magento Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order -> **Send Order Email Copy To**
[image]

Comment: Do you think there is a way to configure bcc for the reset password attempts ?

Comment: There's no configuration level setting available, but, from back-end coding, that can be achievable!